# Access CloudSearch from API Gateway only

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudsearch

I would like to access CloudSearch only from API Gateway, because I don't like the idea of having public access to my CloudSearch endpoint. I tried adding an access policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*********:user/admin"
      },
      "Action": [
        "cloudsearch:search",
        "cloudsearch:suggest"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to access the CloudSearch endpoint from my browser I get `User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: cloudsearch:search`.

API Gateway gets `"Request forbidden by administrative rules"`.

My API Gateway endpoint is HTTP GET and the URI is set to my cloudsearch endpoint. Am I doing things correctly? How do people set this up usually, it's my first time using both services. I'm using CloudSearch for an autocomplete input field on a website.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to setup the Trust Relationship on your IAM role that API Gateway is using, otherwise it will not be able to assume the role. Check the docs [here under 'Prerequisites'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/api-gateway.html)

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }]
}
```

Also make sure you enable CORS in your API or that can throw an error as well.